# Check screen name for only one hyphen/underscore

Tags: java, regex, validation

I need to validate a user's screen name to make sure that it can not have **more than one hyphen or underscore** I don't want people's screen names to be all punctuation.

This is the validation I have so far:

```
public boolean validateScreenName(String screenName) {
  // Check screen name has > 0 chars and that it contains only a-z, A-Z, _ and -
  boolean validated = false;

  if (screenName.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,20}") 
      && (! screenName.equals("")) 
      && (! screenName.contains("\\s"))) {
    validated = true; 
  } else {
    validated = false;
  }
  return validated;
}
```

I want to add the no-multiple-hyphen/underscore validation as another if condition maybe in the form of a RegEx?

Comment: How about the extra regex `"[a-zA-Z0-9]*[-_]?[a-zA-Z0-9]*"`? This allows 0 or 1 underscore (remove the `?` to make it 1 mandatory underscore).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
screenName.matches("^(?=[^_-]*[_-]?[^_-]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,20}$")
```

The other conditions are not needed, they are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already valid what the word contains. You can add this check in another if condition.

```
screenName.matches("[^-]*-?[^-]*")
```